# Find frequency for non-binned, weighted data

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, histogram, bin

Here is a tricky problem (or at least so I think). I need to create a histogram, but instead of having the data and it's frequency, I have repeated data (i.e. not binned) and some weight for each data.

One example:

```
Angle  | Weight    
90   ....  3/10     
93   ....  2/10   
180  ....  2/10    
180  ....  1/10    
95   ....  2/10
```

I want to create a histogram with bin size 10.  The y-values should be the sum of weighted frequencies for angles within a range. How can I do it? Preferably Mathematica or pseudocode...

Comment: this doesn't seem clear. what is 10-Y? Using your example data how would you like that binned?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I believe they're separate sentences. Read it as "... bin size 10; Y values being ...".

Comment: indeed, it should be a separator.

Comment: Please include the output you expect for the example given.

Answer (score 2):

In Mathematica 9, you can do it using the [WeightedData](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WeightedData.html?q=WeightedData&lang=en) function like this:

```
Histogram[WeightedData[{90, 93, 180, 180, 95}, {3/10, 2/10, 2/10, 1/10, 2/10}], {10}]
```

You should then get a graphic like this one:

[image: Weighted Histogram]

Comment: `WeightedData` doesn't seem to work with `Histogram`, unfortunately. The output doesn't seem to make much sense; for example, try `Histogram[WeightedData[{1, 3, 1}, {0, 1, 0}], {0, 4, 2}]`...

Comment: @WillVousden I do not get what is it that you are trying to accomplish, WeigthedData works for the purpose of the question as it was stated.. Can you elaborate on what are you hoping to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Since the expected output is not forthcoming I shall adopt Verbeia's interpretation.  You might use something like this:

```
dat = {{90, 3/10}, {93, 1/5}, {180, 1/5}, {180, 1/10}, {95, 1/5}};

bars =
 Reap[
   Sow[#2, Floor[#, 10]] & @@@ dat,
   _,
   {#, Tr@#2} &
 ][[2]]

Graphics[
  Rectangle[{#, 0}, {# + 10, #2}] & @@@ bars,
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
  Axes -> True,
  AxesOrigin -> {Min@bars[[All, 1]], 0}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar for a different kind of question recently (weighting by balance sheet size).

Assuming your data is in an N * 2 matrix list, I would do something like:

```
{numbers,weights} = {data[[All,1]], data[[All,2]]*10};

weightednumbers =       Flatten@ MapThread[
    Table[#1, {#2}] &, {numbers, Ceiling[weights]}];
```

And then use `Histogram` to draw the histogram on this transformed data.

There might be other ways but this works.

An important point is to make sure the weights are integers, so the `Table` as the correct iterator. This might require defining `weights`  as `data[[All,2]]*Min[data[[All,2]]`.

Comment: I think you could probably use `GatherBy` and then take the dot product of each "bin" -- e.g. `bin1[[All,1]].bin1[[All,2]]`